# How to fix this code? Enable the java parseDouble in scalafx program

Tags: scala, scalafx

I am a new learner of scala and I am coding a simple scalafx calculator and now I face a problem. I cannot find another suitable code to replace the parseDouble. I know the parseDouble is the member of java double, not scala double. I just put the code here to express my thoughts. Can someone help me to fix the code?
[image]

Comment: Please share any relevant code by editing your Question - [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke the Java parser directly...

```
val n1 = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(display.getText())
```

...or you can use the Scala `.toDouble`.

```
val n1 = display.getText().toDouble
```